# Send Excel file to client's printer

Tags: php, excel, printing

i have a PHP web site and i am writing some data to an Excel file. My Excel file can be downloaded with a button. It opens a window or download manager (if configured). So far everything is ok. Now i want to send this file **automatically** to the Client's default printer. When users click print, web page must send the "EXCEL FILE" to printer. NOT like the "window.print()" function in JavaScript.

Is there a way to do this with javascript or AJAX ? Does the client have to download the Excel file in order to send it to default printer ? I tried to use a hidden "iframe" with "src = bla_bla.xls" but it automatically opens the download window.

Briefly i want this **Excel** file, which is prepared on server, to be sent to **client's default printer** and open up the print options window.

Comment: NO, thankfully, just imagine the advertisements that would spit out if your printer if this was possible.

Comment: I want the user to prompt the print window, i mean press OK and then sond it to printer. Not everything automatically. I just want the excel file to be printed. Not whole page. PDF files can be opened in a hidden Iframe and can be sent to printer with "window.print()" code. But unfortunately it is not the same with Excel files.

Comment: don't think i get the question, but as a browser has no native support for an excel file, it has to ask the client machine how to handle it, so you get the open\save dialogue.

Comment: you are right. browser doesn't know how to handle excel file so asks me what to do. but this is Iframe solution, i mean i am trying to open it inside of an i frame. I have to find another way to accomplish this. I mean without embedding in a frame or something. just send the file to printer and print options windows opens.

Comment: This is not possible. The Excel-file is displayed in Excel and you can't control excel via Javascript. Why don't you render the data in a HTML-Table and print that?

Comment: I found some activex ideas for this but turns out there are security obstacles etc. they say open the excel with activex object and print it but every user must enable activex options !! So it may be possible but it is almost impossible by my way. I am insisting on excel ( thanks to my boss :) but i am started to think the best way is to write to an html page and print it. Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this ... you need a client-side scriptlanguage like javascript or vb. php is server-side and don't know anything about the client's printer ..

Comment: thank you. i know all these things. It appears i need a client side script language but how to send the excel file to printer? I can use Iframe and window.print() function to print a PDF file, but if i try to load an Excel file, it opens the download window and doesn't show anything inside of the Iframe.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problems you are getting with the security obstacles with activex is because you are embedding excel into a webpage. It should be posssible to print a worksheet by publishing the sheet as HTML using Excel's publish method. I use this to create an HTML for emails.

```
Dim rngeTableRange As Range
Dim lsTableFileName As String

lsTableFileName = <filepath and name for HTML output as string>
Set rngeTableRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, lsTableFileName, _
rngeTableRange.Parent.Name, rngeTableRange.Address, xlHtmlStatic).Publish True
```

If you want the printout to appear to be a spreadsheet you can add borders before publishing the worksheet. The following VBA code will put a border around each cell:

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
```

The result should be an HTML image of the spreadheet that dosn't lead to the security warnings and I would assume would be printable.